# Fazer uma consulta no banco de dados através de um array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Olá,

Pessoal estou com uma grande dúvida aqui.
Tenho uma consulta onde o usuário pode selecionar se quer ver todos(Gerente e Gerentes Jr), Só gerentes Jr, ou Selecionar diretamente apenas um.

1. Todos
2. Só gerentes Jr
3. João
4. Maria
5. etc...

O problema é quando seleciono a opção "2 - Só gerentes Jr".

Porque tenho que ir no cadastro de funcionários e saber quem são os gerentes junior `(colab_func=3)`, até ai tudo bem.

Depois da consulta anterior, onde recebo os códigos dos funcionários, preciso fazer a consulta propriamente dita, onde vou na tabela de vendas e procuro as vendas desses funcionários. 
É ai que não estou conseguindo.

Vou colocar uma parte do código aqui:

```
$gerente = $_POST["txtgerente"];
if($gerente == 'T'){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM venda_dia WHERE venda_dia_aberto='S'";
    $tipo = "Todos";
} elseif ($gerente == 'GJR'){
    $query_ger = "SELECT colab_id FROM colaborador WHERE colab_funcao in($cod_gerjr)";
    $result_ger = mysqli_query($con, $query_ger) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_ger = mysqli_fetch_array($result_ger);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM venda_dia WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger in($row_ger) AND venda_dia_aberto='S'";
    $tipo = "Gerente Júnior";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM venda_dia WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger='$gerente' AND venda_dia_aberto='S'";
    $query_gerente = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_id=$gerente";
    $result_gerente = mysqli_query($con, $query_gerente) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_gerente = mysqli_fetch_array($result_gerente);
    $tipo = $row_gerente['colab_nome_venda'];
}
?>

<section id="cadastros">
    <fieldset id="cadastros"><legend><?php echo "Expositor com dia aberto - $tipo"; ?></legend>
         <table id="tab" align="center">
             <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                 <th width="250px">Expositor</th>
                 <th width="150px">Dia Faturamento</th>
                 <th width="250px">Responsável</th>
              </tr>
              <?php 
                   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
                   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $cod_exp = $row["venda_dia_cod_exp"];
                        $data = $row["venda_dia_data"];
                        $cod_colab = $row["venda_dia_cod_colab"];
                        $cod_colab2 = $row["venda_dia_cod_colab2"];

                        // ESCREVE UMA LINHA NA TABELA
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        $query_expositor = "SELECT * FROM expositor WHERE expo_id=$cod_exp";
                        $result_expositor = mysqli_query($con, $query_expositor) or die(mysqli_error());
                             while ($row_expositor = mysqli_fetch_array($result_expositor)) {
                                 $nome_expo = $row_expositor["expo_nome"];
                                 echo $nome_expo . "</td>";
                         }
                         echo "<td id='centro'>" . date('d/m/Y' , strtotime($data)). "</td>";
                         echo "<td>";
                         if($cod_colab2 == 0){
                             $query_colab = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_id=$cod_colab";
                             $result_colab = mysqli_query($con, $query_colab) or die(mysqli_error());
                             while ($row_colab = mysqli_fetch_array($result_colab)) {
                                   $colab_nome = $row_colab["colab_nome_venda"];
                                   echo $colab_nome . "</td>";
                              }
                          } else {
                              $query_colab = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE colab_id=$cod_colab2";
                              $result_colab = mysqli_query($con, $query_colab) or die(mysqli_error());
                              while ($row_colab = mysqli_fetch_array($result_colab)) {
                                    $colab_nome = $row_colab["colab_nome_venda"];
                                    echo $colab_nome . "</td>";
                              }
                           }
                           echo "</tr>";
                        }
             ?>
```

Ao executar, me dá o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema_1_1\est_exp_opened.php on line 65

A linha 65:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venda_dia WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger in($row_ger) AND venda_dia_aberto='S'";
```

Obrigado pela ajuda desde já...

Comment: `$row_ger` é um array de resultados da primeira consulta, você pode dar um um `implode(', ', $row_ger);` ou mesmo fazer uma única consulta substituindo `WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger in($row_ger)` por `WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger in($query_ger)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é que você está passando uma array (resultante de `$row_ger = mysqli_fetch_array($result_ger)`) dentro do `IN`.

O `IN` aceita constantes (um ou mais valores separados por vírgula: `valor1[,valor2...]`) ou uma query (`"SELECT Id FROM..."`) que retorne uma coluna.

Neste caso, basta você colocar no `IN` a variável da query (`$query_ger`):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venda_dia WHERE venda_dia_cod_ger in($query_ger) AND venda_dia_aberto='S'";
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou blz.